# How to increase the PUT request size limitation in python-requests?

Tags: python, python-requests, put

I'm reading the content from file and send PUT request to the API, the code is

```
json_dict = {
    'name': 'test records',
    'records': ','.join([elem.strip() for elem in open(file_path).readlines()])}

r = requests.put(url, params=json_dict)
print r.url
print r.request.body
print r.text
```

It works if the file content is short, but it got error below when I increased the file:

```
    r = requests.put(url, params=json_dict)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 122, in put
    return request('put', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 412, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('<html>\r\n',))
```

Additionally, it works well if I'm using `curl`, so i think it's in python requests side. How to increase the PUT request limitation?

Moreover, is this the only way to upload a file? (use `records: <file_content>`)

Comment: should it not be `data=...`? What curl command are you using?

Comment: I think it's `params=...`, and it is working with small number of records.    my curl command line is:   ```curl -X PUT -F "records=asf@gmail1.com,asf@gmail1.com,asf@gmail1.com,asf@gmail1.com,asf@gmail1.com" -F "name=test records" "https://..."```